# VBA - Range Selection - Serious Trouble

Tags: vba, excel

I am just trying to copy the contents of one WB into another

```
strColNos = Range(Cells(65536, rngSMonthYr.Column).Address(False, False)).End(xlUp).Row
For intLastCell = 2 To strColNos
    strCell1 = Cells(intLastCell, rngSMonthYr.Column).Address(False, False)
    strCell2 = Cells(intLastCell, rngDMonthYr.Column).Address(False, False)

    Workbooks(wkbSource).Sheets(wsSource).Range(strCell1).Copy _
        Destination:=Workbooks(wkbDestination).Sheets(wsDestination).Range(strCell2)
Next intLastCell
```

strCell1 has value "D2" (Source Book), strCell2 has value "F2" (Destination Book)

rngSMonthYr, rngDMonthYr are basically input boxes where users get to select a particular month from source and destination sheets. I need to copy all the rows from selected source column to selected destination column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: hi, can you show the rest of the script with the input boxes and if you have error(s), what error(s) do you get?

Comment: you do not need to have a workbook open to reference data from it. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet/17838174#17838174) explaining how to pull data from a closed workbook.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop through every single cell. Also, you can address range without converting them to address strings all the time. This code should do what you need:

```
intLastRow = Cells(65536, rngSMonthYr.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Cells(2, rngSMonthYr.Column).Resize(intLastRow - 1).Copy _
    Sheet2.Cells(2, rngDMonthYr.Column).Resize(intLastRow - 1)
```

I'm not sure, if you need to use `rngSMonthYr.Column` - or if `rngSMonthYr` is enough. If the cell contains the column number, `.Column` is wrong and must be omitted.